# Have shapes/pictures below each other instead of on top

Tags: excel, vba

I found this peice of code:

```
With ws.Shapes
        numShp = .Count
        If numShp > 1 Then
            autoShp = 0
            ReDim shpArray(1 To numShp)
            For y = 1 To numShp
                If .Item(y).Type = msoAutoShape Then
                    autoShp = autoShp + 1
                    shpArray(autoShp) = .Item(y).Name
                End If
            Next y
            If autoShp > 1 Then
                ReDim Preserve shpArray(1 To autoShp)
                Set asRng = .Range(shpArray)
                asRng.Distribute msoDistributeVertically, False
            End If
        End If
    End With
```

It pretty much does what I need with the rest of my code, but each shape/picture object is on top of each other. I need them to be positioned below each other.
Another valued member suggest I use this code to order the pictures, but I got an the 'index into the specified collection is out of bounds' error at `ws.Shapes(0).Top = 0`:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = xlBook.Sheets("Sheet2")

With ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count)
  .UnMerge
   rng.CopyPicture appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
   .PasteSpecial
 End With

 If ws.Shapes.Count = 1 Then ' position at top
    ws.Shapes(0).Top = 0
 Else
  ws.Shapes(ws.Shapes.Count).Top = ws.Shapes(ws.Shapes.Count - 1).Height + 5 ' or whatever gap      you want
 End If
```

I've been scraping the interwebs with no luck.

Comment: there is no `Shapes(0)` it starts at 1

Comment: What happens if you just flip `For y = 1 To numShp` into `For y = numShp To 1 Step -1`. That would re-order the pictures and get them the way you want, right?

Comment: @toddleson There is an object variable or with block variable not set error at numShp = .count

Comment: and @Warcupine it didn't error out, but the shapes are still on top of each other

Comment: is numShp an object variable?

Comment: I did set the ws to the current sheet i'm using. I tried to change it to ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") as that is the sheet I'm using, but I still get the error. And I set it as shape for. I must have forgot to change it back

Comment: That line would only trigger if there is one shape, but increase the `+ 5` to `+ 30` or something, and if you have more than two shapes it will need to be in a loop because it only moves the last shape just below the second to last shape (created)

Comment: @warcupine I would essentially need to combine both codes to loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to focus on the second of the code blocks, based on your question / comments I don't think that the first one is actually what you are looking for.

In the second I added a loop so it handles all your shapes. It will place them on the left starting at the top.

I fixed the calculations in the `Else` statement that was going to overlap if you have more than two shapes since it didn't factor in the starting location.

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
    For i = 1 To ws.Shapes.Count
        If i = 1 Then ' position at top
            ws.Shapes(i).Top = 5 ' You can do 0 but it looks (isn't actually) off screen a little.
        Else
            ws.Shapes(i).Top = ws.Shapes(i - 1).Top + ws.Shapes(i - 1).Height + 5 ' or whatever gap you want
        End If
    Next
```